# How to make an element not extend the parent div's scrollable area?

Tags: css

I have tooltips for certain elements that might get really large - so large that I can't position them on any side of the cursor without going outside of the page. Is there any way to prevent scrollbars from appearing in that case (besides setting body to `overflow:hidden`)?

I think it should be possible to make a fullscreen div to contain the tooltips, and set it to have overflow hidden, but I'm hoping there is a better solution.

*Update*: okay this was pretty simple. Just append the following div to body and place all tooltips inside it.

```
.tooltip-body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: It does not have to be `body` and you can set `overflow-x: hidden` (note: -x). But there is a question: why would you show the tooltip if it cannot be read at all? Have you tried to center tooltip if there is not enough space (or to align it left or right to content)? Have you tried [tooltipster](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/)?

Comment: Its an image (sort of), so I can't do much about it. I'd rather show part of it than mess up my layout. What about overflow-y though?

Comment: Than just do `overflow-x` hidden to some parent container. *If you put overflow-y to body - you may have problems (combined with height: 100% won't be able to scroll down). Maybe you can try somehow to make tooltips `position: fixed` also, that would not show scrollbars if out of screen.